# Limiting SQL Server Transaction log

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-delete, archive

I currently have a SQL script that takes all the tables with a certain name and deletes records from it.

There are millions of records in these tables so the transaction log keeps growing even with recovery set to SIMPLE. I am putting the delete in side a transaction and it's only deleting around 50000 records at a time. Can anyone suggest some way to not let the transaction log grow uncontrollably. Below is the rough example of the SQL I am running.

```
DECLARE delete_cur CURSOR FOR   
SELECT DISTINCT Name FROM Sys.tables WHERE name like 'ToDelete_%'

OPEN delete_cur
FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cur
INTO @tableName  
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 AND @timeToStop = 0
BEGIN
    SELECT @RowCount = NULL, @MaxID = NULL, @MinID = NULL, @ID = NULL, @TableRowCount = 0               

    IF NOT Exists (Select 1 from ArchiveInfoAuditTables WHERE Name = @tableName)
    BEGIN
        SET @params = N'@MaxID_Out DECIMAL(18,0) OUT, @MinID_Out DECIMAL(18,0) OUT, @RowCount_Out DECIMAL(18,0) OUT';

        SET @SQL = 'SELECT @RowCount_Out = COUNT(ID), @MaxID_Out = MAX(ID), @MinID_Out = MIN(ID) FROM ' + @tableName
        print @SQL
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @params, @RowCount_Out = @RowCount OUT, @MaxID_Out = @MaxID OUT, @MinID_Out = @MinID OUT;          
        PRINT @tableName + ' Row Count: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @RowCount) + ' Max ID: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @MaxID)  + ' Min ID: ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, @MinID)      

        SET @params = N'@ID_Out DECIMAL(18,0) OUT, @Date DATETIME';

        SET @SQL = 'SELECT TOP 1 @ID_Out = ID FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE AuditTimeStamp < @Date ORDER BY ID DESC'
        print @SQL
        EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @params, @ID_Out = @ID OUT, @Date = @JanOfCurrentYear          

        INSERT INTO DeleteInfo (Name, StartDeletingFromID, MaxID, MinID, NumberOfRows)
            VALUES (@tableName, @ID, @MaxID, @MinID, @RowCount)
    END
    ELSE 
    BEGIN
        SELECT TOP 1 @ID = StartDeletingFromID FROM DeleteInfo WHERE Name = @tableName          
    END

    IF (@ID IS NULL)
    BEGIN 
        PRINT 'No Record needs to be deleted for Table: ' + @tableName
        GOTO Fetch_Next
    END 

    WHILE 1 = 1
        BEGIN
            BEGIN TRANSACTION
                SET @params = N'@RowCount_Out DECIMAL(18,0) OUT, @NumOfRowsToDelete_Out BIGINT, @ID_Out DECIMAL(18,0)'
                SET @SQL = 'DELETE TOP (@NumOfRowsToDelete_Out) FROM ' + @tableName + ' WHERE ID <= @ID_Out ;' 
                + 'SELECT @RowCount_Out = @@RowCount'

                PRINT @SQL 
                EXEC sp_executesql @SQL, @params, @RowCount_Out = @TempRowCount OUT, @NumOfRowsToDelete_Out = @NumOfRowsToDelete, @ID_Out = @ID

                SET @TableRowCount += @TempRowCount
                SET @TotalRowCount += @TableRowCount
            COMMIT TRANSACTION
            CHECKPOINT;

            SET @MSG = 'Deleted ' + CAST(@TableRowCount AS VARCHAR) + '. ' + CONVERT(varchar, @TimeElapsed) + ' elapsed.'
            RAISERROR (@MSG, 0, 1) WITH NOWAIT  
            IF @TempRowCount < @NumOfRowsToDelete BREAK;
        END

    Fetch_Next:
        PRINT '/******************************************************************/'
        FETCH NEXT FROM delete_cur   
        INTO @tableName         

END

END_HERE:
    CLOSE delete_cur;  
    DEALLOCATE delete_cur;
```

Comment: I could not see any  ROLLBACK? Also, could you check this query when the query is still running "SELECT name, log_reuse_wait_desc FROM sys.databases;"

Answer (score 0):

You can limit the size of the log (here we limit the size to 512 MB):

```
ALTER DATABASE [DatabaseName] MODIFY FILE ( NAME = N'DATABASENAME_Log', SIZE = 512000KB , FILEGROWTH = 0)
```

Create a maintenance job for backups the DB and shrinks the log

you can use this simple command to shrink the log file

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE (DataFile1, 512)
```